# Fabric SDK for Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I have successfully implemented the Login part of `"Fabric SDK"` in my Android App.

Now I am trying to fetch the logged in user's Email Id.

I have went through  [Fabric's Twitter Kit](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/request-email). There they have mentioned

> "Requesting a user’s email address requires your application to be
>   white-listed by Twitter. To request access, please use form."

Now in that form, there are lots of options, but they have not mentioned that which options should i choose for white-listing.?

Can any one please help me on how can i get my app white-listed to fetch user's email id through fabric sdk????

Answer (score 1):

Just like you I didn't find a specific form to ask to be whitelisted. Personally I went on their form link https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform and I checked the "I have an API policy question not covered by these points" option. They responded a few days after by asking me more information about the application and its app ID. I'm actually waiting for their answer.

EDIT:

I've been emailing with **support@fabric.io** and I finally got whitelisted. But the option is currently unavailable with Fabric so you'll have to create a Twitter app on [apps.twitter.com](http://apps.twitter.com). Just send a mail with your app ID or your keys and a quick description of your app and it shouldn't take so much time to be whitelisted.

Comment: so does your app has to be a published in order to be whitelisted?

Comment: No, you can do it now.